# Get HTML of page as String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the html of a page as a string when it finishes loading:

```
    protected void OnPreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringWriter strWrt = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmText = new HtmlTextWriter(strWrt);
        base.Render(htmText);
        html = strWrt.GetStringBuilder();
    }
```

This however is resulting in the html string being being null... so its not pulling. I also tried to do it on render:

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        StringWriter strWrt = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmText = new HtmlTextWriter(strWrt);
        base.Render(htmText);
        html = strWrt.GetStringBuilder();
    }
```

But when I do this the page doesn't render. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps something on `Page.Response` will get the html for you without re-rendering the page.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with this? Perhaps there's a better way of accomplishing your goal. Are you going to use the HTML as part of an AJAX response? Are you going to use the HTML in an email body?

Comment: I am going to build a PDF file for output/download from the HTML

Comment: In that case, rendering the entire Web Forms page is complete overkill. Web pages contain JavaScript, CSS, and navigation elements that aren't appropriate for display in a PDF. A better approach would be to create a ViewModel that represents the data that you want the PDF to contain, then create another class that accepts that ViewModel as a parameter and either generates the HTML or generates the PDF (using your PDF library's native UI builder rather than HTML).

Comment: If you decide to go the HTML route, look into using a rendering engine to build the HTML, like the way [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) does, as it will simplify the HTML building. Although Postal is meant for emails, you may use it or emulate the technique it's using to get the HTML from the Razor view engine. Also related may be this helpful information from [Xamarin](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the page doesn't render because you are not doing anything with the writer parameter.
You cant just call Render with each instance of HtmlTextWriter though, so another approach is needed...

The following partial **TextWriter** implementation allows me to capture the html, and render a page.
There might be other Write methods which need to be overloaded to complete the solution...

```
...
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        var stringWriter = new TextWriterDecorator(writer.InnerWriter);
        writer.InnerWriter = stringWriter;
        base.Render(writer);

        var html = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder();
    }
}

public class TextWriterDecorator : StringWriter
{
    readonly TextWriter writer;

    public TextWriterDecorator(TextWriter writer)
    {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        this.writer.Write(value);
        base.Write(value);
    }

    public override void Write(char[] buffer)
    {
        this.writer.Write(buffer);
        base.Write(buffer);
    }

    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        this.writer.Write(buffer, index, count);
        base.Write(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void Write(string format)
    {
        this.writer.Write(format);
        base.Write(format);
    }
}
```